# Gamepad | Unity | C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь через геймпад управлять персонажом. Использую InputActions. Сделал все как по урокам юнити. Все работало, пока я не повернул персонажа. Хоть он и продолжает двигаться, но по смещенным осям (точнее они остаются прежними, а персонаж смещается). Как итог, вместо того, чтобы идти направо, он идет вперед и т.п.

```
public float speedMove = 5f;
    public float rotatePower = 2f;
    float gravityForce;

    CharacterController ch;

    Vector2 moveInput;
    Vector2 rotateInput;

    Control inputSystem;
    Animator anim;

    private void Awake()
    {
        inputSystem = new Control();
        inputSystem.Gameplay.Grow.performed += ctx => Grow();

        inputSystem.Gameplay.Move.performed += ctx => moveInput = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        //inputSystem.Gameplay.Move.canceled += ctx => moveInput = Vector2.zero;

        inputSystem.Gameplay.Rotate.performed += ctx => rotateInput = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        //inputSystem.Gameplay.Rotate.canceled += ctx => rotateInput = Vector2.zero;
    }

    private void Grow()
    {
        transform.localScale *= 1.1f;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        ch = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 move = new Vector3();
        move.x = moveInput.x * speedMove;
        move.z = moveInput.y * speedMove;

        Debug.Log(moveInput);

        if(Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, new Vector3(Mathf.Abs(move.x), Mathf.Abs(move.y), Mathf.Abs(move.z))) > 1f || Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, new Vector3(Mathf.Abs(move.x), Mathf.Abs(move.y), Mathf.Abs(move.z))) == 0)
        {
            Vector3 direction = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, move, speedMove, 0f);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
        }

        gravity();
        move.y = gravityForce;

        ch.Move(move * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    private void gravity()
    {
        if (!ch.isGrounded) gravityForce -= 20f * Time.deltaTime;
        else gravityForce = -1f;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        inputSystem.Gameplay.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        inputSystem.Gameplay.Disable();
    }
```

Кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Что делать?

Comment: каким именно урокам юнити? Официальным или каких-то рандомных людей из интернета? Советую пользоваться официальными уроками (как видео так и просто документацией)

Comment: Как минимум меня смущает кастомная реализация гравитации что уже само по себе дичайший костыль и такого ужаса вряд ли можно найти в официальных уроках юнити. Настоятельно советую дальше эти уроки не использовать.

Comment: Официальный урок по настройке геймпада.

Comment: Можно линк? А гравитацию сам пилил вот эту? Почему не использовал rigitbody?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gz0YcjXBJ3U
Физику сам написал. Rigidbody с Terrain не дружит у меня. Просто проваливается вниз.

Comment: Лучше разберись что не так с террейном что риджитбоди проваливается. Вероятно, ты просто коллайдер удалил) Ну или же у тебя метод  Grow проваливает низ коллайдера сквозь террейн и нужно разместить пивотпоинт в самый низ персонажа. А когда код почистится от всякого лишнего мусора будет легче разбираться и с этой проблемой.

Comment: Grow вызывается только после нажатия X. А collider у меня на CharacterController активирован.

Comment: Вообще писать свою реализацию физики просто потому что "почему-то не работает стандартная" - это весьма плохая мотивация. Ты не напишешь такую же хорошую физику как разработчики юнити и твоя физика породит тебе столько проблем, что.... дешевле по времени разобраться что не так со стандартной) уж поверь)